# Ethereum, which syncmode to use, fast or full?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, go-ethereum, geth

There is a `geth` program running, and provide `--rpc` service.

**What the service do:**

- Sync blocks.
- Accept rpc requests to create transaction.
- There is another program try to read the new blocks, and find out the transactions relevant to addresses in our wallets, and sync the data into local database (e.g `mysql`).

Currently we are using `full` mode, but it's a bit slow, and takes more disk space.

---

### Questions

- Is `fast` mode enough for above usage?
- Which is better?
- If we switch from `full` mdoe to `fast` mode, will `geth` have to re-download all the years of historys? Or, it will reuse the history?

---

*(I asked another question about ethereum on `Ethereum` site, if you are interested could you also take a look: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/78293/how-to-migrate-geths-data)*

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should probably use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question. Also see [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**full sync** downloads all blocks of the blockchain and replays all transactions that ever happened. While doing so, it stores the receipts of transactions and continuously updates the state database.

**fast sync** does not replay transactions. This quote from the [fast sync pull request](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/pull/1889) describes it well (You can also find additional information there).

> Instead of processing the entire block-chain one link at a time, and
>   replay all transactions that ever happened in history, fast syncing
>   downloads the transaction receipts along the blocks, and pulls an
>   entire recent state database.

Note that it also downloads receipts so historical data can be queried.

---

- Is fast mode enough for above usage?

  fast sync is used only for initially getting the blockchain. After the fast sync process ended, your node acts just as a full synced node. Since a fast synced node also has all the historical data, it is suitable for your use-case.
- Which is better?

  Depends on. In case of full sync, you need processing power, while in the other case, you need bandwidth.
- If we switch from full mode to fast mode, will geth have to re-download all the
  years of history? Or, it will reuse the history?

  For security reasons, you can not switch the sync mode of an already running node.